# Adding Long Press Gesture in Xamarin.Forms for iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a navigation button that requires multiple gestures to be implemented.
Single Tap, Double Tap, Swipe, and Hold
I have already implemented Tap and Pan.. But I cannot implement Hold, so I made a custom renderer, View to be exact and I have followed the Long Tap implementation provided from this link https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-gestures-in-xamarin-forms/ Now implementing the Long Tap in a custom renderer works but it's not really working along with the XF built-in gestures.

Here's my actual code
[image]
Red box was the built-in XF gestures and the green box was my implementation of my View custom renderer. Now my issue is, the built-in XF gestures are not working because it's covering my view custom renderer.

Creating a custom gesture recognizer based on IGestureRecognizer does not work as well as you can see, it was commented out in the redbox and I am not sure why.

How do you exactly implement LongPress that will work with built-in XF gestures?